# How can i make a custom user model in django without using username field?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on building a project and for this, i need to create a custom user model, since the one that Django comes with isn't suitable for my situation, so whenever i use the AbstractBaseUser, I am forced to use the username field, which i really don't need in my case. how can I create a custom user model without using the username field and thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After many attempts, i finally could fix it by overiding it in the accountmanager

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
import uuid


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    
    def _create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an userusername")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an userusername")

        user = self.model(
                    email=self.normalize_email(email),
                    first_name=first_name,
                    last_name=last_name,
                )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email,first_name, last_name, password):
        user = self._create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                first_name= first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
            )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_active = True 
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def verifyAccount(self, user, user_input, code):
        if user_input == code:
            user.is_active = True
            user.save(using=self._db)
            return user



class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)    
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = MyAccountManager()


    def __str__(self):
            return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```